# How to send an array of JSON objects to Laravel from Vue.js with AXIOS

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, vue.js, axios

So, my Laravel API endpoint would like to receive something like this to succesfully add it to DB:

```
{
  ICAO: 'ABC',
  name: 'The name of Airport',
  place: 'city',
  country: 'country'
}
```

I made parser which takes .csv file and parse it, and I want to send something like this with axios:

```
[
  {
    ICAO: 'ABC',
    name: 'The name of Airport',
    place: 'city',
    country: 'country'
  },
  {
    ICAO: 'DEF',
    name: 'The name of Airport',
    place: 'city',
    country: 'country'
  },
  {
    ICAO: 'GHI',
    name: 'The name of Airport',
    place: 'city',
    country: 'country'
  },
  {
    ICAO: 'JKL',
    name: 'The name of Airport',
    place: 'city',
    country: 'country'
  }
]
```

So I could iterate this array with foreach thus adding all objects within it to db.

```
  public function import(Request $request)
  {
    // Do validation
    $airports = $request->all();
    foreach ($airports as $airport) {
      Airport::create($airport)
    };

    return response('Airports imported', 200);
  }
```

I even tried sending one object with property 'data' which has value of aforementioned array of JSON objects and then tried to iterate over that prop.

It all works in postman, but when trying to send it with app, it doesn't work or it fills DB with empty rows.

I also use vuex store so my action for posting this is:

```
 importAirports (payload) {
  if (auth.roles('Operative')) {
    axios.post(api + '/airports/import?token=' + token, payload, { headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' } })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      commit('error', error)
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

Basic creation of one Airport works fine, as everything else but this doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: dd($request->all()); doesn't even work since app is divided in two separate parts - client and server side and data is passed with AJAX requests (restfulAPI). I'm not sure how to debug this.

Comment: right forgot that detail, if you do return response()->json($request->all()); open up console in browser go to network and press XHR and check the response

Comment: Normally if you sent. json formated correctly; $request->all(); should cast it to array. So your code in backend its right but not sure if you are sending the correct data

Comment: it returns gibberish (vuex actions, mutations involved and that kind of stuff) without my data... and again when doing the same (returning request as response) but with postman it returns data that I sent. It's really weird.

Comment: if u are using l5.5 and if that token is csrf then you do not need to include it on as param on call. try  `axios.post(api + '/airports/import', { payload  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      commit('error', error)
      console.log(error)
    }); `

Comment: It will cast proper json like {{obj},{obj}, {obj}} to array [ 0:{obj}, 1:{obj}, 2:{obj} ]? That may be the case. I will post if it worked, thanks :D

Comment: post the url that you fire the request towards to from postman.

Comment: oh, that token is not built-in Laravel CSRF, it's for authentification purposes. JWT stuff.

Comment: okay then make sure you are getting the token propperly. like if its defined in that vue component as var then. you should access this.token. Inspect element network when you fire the request check if url its correctly on network tab.

Comment: my apologies for not being clear about it

Comment: np, did u get anything working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue here may lie within the Vuex action. To my knowledge, a Vuex action's first parameter is the 'context' followed by a second parameter which is the payload. Your action params should look like this:

```
importAirports (context, payload) {
// do stuff
}
```

You can then use destructuring to get access to methods like `commit`, which I see you use in your `.catch()` block. Like this:

```
 importAirports ({ commit }, payload) {
  if (auth.roles('Operative')) {
    axios.post(api + '/airports/import?token=' + token, payload, { headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' } })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      commit('error', error)
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right, i deleted {commit} for posting here, and I forgot  to delete this commit('error', error) since I actually don't need that. Can action send axios.post() request without passing the context object and without commiting?

Comment: actually, { commit } is needed whether you use commit('something', something) or not. Second thing, the prop that contained JSON array was named 'data', which is used so by renaming it to something else I was able to iterate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `Get` method in `Post` request. In that way Laravel create you empty `$request`.

Try like this.

`axios.post('your_route', {data: 'json_data_here"}, callback)`

Comment: doesn't axios.post() send POST request? 'your route' is = api + '/airports/import?token=' + token (token and api var), and payload is data since im using vuex.Not sure if I understand, but thanks. :)